# Is there a Mathematica version of ODE tools pplane and dfield?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, matlab

The toolkits [dfield and pplane](http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html) are staples in ODE courses. First in MATLAB, now in Java. Do they have a Mathematica expression?

Sample outputs follow:

[image: pplane]
[image: dfield]

---

**@Michael E2**

Your suggestions were great. Here are the results.

[EquationTrekker](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EquationTrekker/):

[image: trekker]

Nice example by @David Slater in [Plotting a Phase Portrait](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait)

---

*Phase portraits*

@Chris Degnen: [Phase Portrait Trajectories](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77119/phase-portrait-trajectories)

@chris: [Plotting a Phase Portrait](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait)

@Kuba♦, @Jens: [Phase portrait on a cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/phase-portrait-on-a-cylinder)

@Alexei Boulbitch: [How to make program for phase portrait?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86721/how-to-make-program-for-phase-portrait)

@yarchik: [Cleaner Approach to Plotting Multiple Solution Curves on Phase Portrait](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123323/cleaner-approach-to-plotting-multiple-solution-curves-on-phase-portrait)

@Artes, @Sektor, @Michael E2: [Phase portraits and StreamPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/phase-portraits-and-streamplot)

@Rahul: [Why isn't my Stream code plotting multiple solution curves?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42763/why-isnt-my-stream-code-plotting-multiple-solution-curves)

@ubpdqn: Posted to this question

---

*Direction Field*

@Jens: [Plotting the direction field of a differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/plotting-the-direction-field-of-a-differential-equation)

@Jens: [Graphics Grid Direction Field Animations as GIF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123374/graphics-grid-direction-field-animations-as-gif)

@Dr. belisarius, @Wesley Wolfe: [How can I plot the direction field for a differential equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/how-can-i-plot-the-direction-field-for-a-differential-equation/8848#8848)

@Kuba♦: [How to plot a vector field on a geographic map?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118971/how-to-plot-a-vector-field-on-a-geographic-map)

Comment: Have you seen [EquationTrekker](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/EquationTrekker/ref/EquationTrekker.html) or search this site for phase portrait or direction field?

Comment: @Michael E2: Had not seen  EquationTrekker; will tinker with it immediately. Had not searched with those keywords. Found many promising links. Thanks, very helpful insights. My hope is to find a package and avoid writing code. Many homework problems are written around the functionality of pplane and dfield, so a close match is desirable.

Comment: @ Michael E2: Please consider promoting your comment to an answer; it deserves a vote.

Comment: @Michael E2: Should the post be deleted, or should the search result be summarized and appended to the OP?

Comment: I'm a bit involved in a family situation and don't have the time to consider answering.  If a good duplicate or two can be found, it might be better to "close" it as a duplicate.  The advantage is that others searching for an equivalent to `dfield` or `pplane` would likely find this question and the linked solutions.

Comment: @Michael E2: Thanks for the idea. Here is a hasty collection, not a curation. Your further insights are welcome.  **Readers:** Please remember to upvote these clever solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of resources on this site (as suggested in the comments and likely to make the question reasonably deemed a duplicate). You can do a lot yourself, e.g.:

```
sp = StreamPlot[{2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y, 
    x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x  y}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 2}];
cp = {x, y} /. 
   NSolve[{2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y, 
      x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x  y} == {0, 0}, {x, y}
    ];
sn = ParametricNDSolve[{{x'[t], 
      y'[t]} == {2 x[t] - y[t] + 3 (x[t]^2 - y[t]^2) + 2 x[t] y[t], 
      x[t] - 3 y[t] - 3 (x[t]^2 - y[t]^2) + 3 x[t]  y[t]}, {x[0], 
      y[0]} == {a, b}}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, {a, b}];
Manipulate[
 Show[sp, ParametricPlot[{x[a, b][t], y[a, b][t]} /. sn, {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Black, Point[{a, b}], Green, Point[cp]},
   PlotLabel -> 
   Column[Thread[{x', y'} == {2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y, 
       x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x  y}]]], {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}]
```

[image]